# creating a burst Camera app based on video

Tags: android, video, image-processing, camera, android-camera

I want to create a burst camera app. I followed quite tutorials about this subject but I always faced a problem with the speed of capture. My question is it possible to create this app but based on video. Like extracting frames from the video and then creating the images.

**EDIT**
The application is on Android platform

Comment: It's probably possible, but without more information (what tutorials? what platform (android/iphone/etc) is the app for? what language?) it's hard to help you.

Comment: It's an android application

Comment: What speed and what resolution (or image quality) do you expect to achieve? How many frames of burst do you need? Which devices do you target? Note that today high-end devices with full support of camera2 API can give you raw frames of 'capture' quality at 30 FPS. Video is often limited to 1080p.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. This app is meant for low end devices, we want at least 10 frames per second and it doesn't matter if we use the minimum resolution possible for the device.